# Using Neo4jTemplate to save data in Rest configuration is too slow

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on the project with Spring and Neo4j database. I configured my Neo4j database to be rest neo4j. This is the configuration:

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data" />
</bean>
```

At the beginning I was using notations on my domain objects (`@NodeEntity`, `@RelatedTo`, etc.) and repositories to save nodes and relationships. My domain objects are **User**(id, name), **Item**(id, name, description, list of terms), **Term**(content, count). So there not so many properties out there, but even so, saving the object through repository, for example a User with defined id and name lasted for **25 seconds**.

I read that this kind of communication with neo4j database is not yet well optimized, so I **switched on using the Neo4jTemplate**.

This is a example of saving the user (constraints in User are Strings ("id", "name", "USER"):

```
public Node saveUser(User user) {
    Node node = template.createNode();
    node.setProperty(User.ID, user.getId());
    node.setProperty(User.NAME, user.getName());
    node.setProperty("_type", User.LABEL);

    template.index(INDEX_ID, node, User.ID, user.getId());
    return node;
}
```

And this is a example of saving the item with relationships to its terms. So each term is a node which is connected to the item:

```
public Node saveItem(Item item) {
    Node node = template.createNode();
    node.setProperty(Item.ID, item.getId());
    node.setProperty(Item.NAME, item.getName());
    node.setProperty(Item.DESCRIPTION, item.getDescription());
    node.setProperty("_type", Item.LABEL);

    template.index(INDEX_ID, node, Item.ID, item.getId());

    for(String termContent : item.getTerms()) {
        Node term = termRepository.getNodeByContent(termContent);
        if(term == null) {
            term = termRepository.saveTerm(new Term(termContent));
        } else {
            termRepository.addCountToTerm(term);
        }

        int frequency = 1;          

        Relationship contains = node.createRelationshipTo(term, RelationshipTypes.CONTAINS);
        contains.setProperty(Term.FREQUENCY, frequency);            
    }
    return node;
}
```

The object `termRepository` (it isn't extending `GraphRespository<Term>`) has methods which are similar to the method of saving the user. Fetching the term is done like this:

```
public Node getNodeByContent(String content) {
    if(!template.getGraphDatabaseService().index().existsForNodes(INDEX_ID))
        return null;
    return template.lookup(INDEX_ID, Term.CONTENT, content).to(Node.class).singleOrNull();
}
```

And, **finally what is my problem**. Even now it is **still slow**, inserting user (only parameters id and name) and indexing it takes for **3 seconds**, and inserting item where it is being connected to terms takes **for 30 seconds** (for 4 terms - which is very small ammount according to the number of 60-70 which I will have in real situation).

Please, can you give me some hint or anything else that could help me with this kind of issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is very strange. How big is the traffic actually going through the HTTP endpoints?

Answer (score 3):

This is really strage, where does your server run? Seems to be something with the network setup.

I mean SDN over REST is not fast, but it is also not that slow.

Can you share your classes too?

You should not do the individual property updates over the wire. Use cypher statements that create all the properties in one go.

There is also neo4jTemplate.createNode(map of properties) which does it as one operation.

Comment: Yes, really strange. My server runs on localhost so there is small latency between application server and neo4j server - but to be sure I will track my network communication through Wireshark.

Thanks for note about individual property. Change it, and it is a little bit faster now. ;)
Also I read here: http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/get-the-full-neo4j-power-by-using-the-core-java-api-for-traversing-your-graph-data-base-instead-of-cypher-query-language/ that core API is faster than Cypher, so I choose to go with the core API
Also, I changed the graph mode to Embedded, and now it is really fast.